# Java filing and highscore

Tags: java, file, methods

Hi so I have an assignment due in 6 hours and I am completely lost. I have new methods added to my existing work done so far but I don't know how to do them.
The text file has names and scores, and the first method needs to check if the score is among the top 10 and return true/false:

the last method that I am lost in needs to write the high score into highscore.txt file, at the correct position(in descending order), the method uses readHighScore() method to find the line number where the record should be inserted.

```
public static void recordHighScore(String name, int score){
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to simply output to a file? Have you gotten the rest figured out?

Comment: You're making this harder than it needs to be I think. Personally I would store the scores in an array when the program loads, then save the file when the program closes. That way you could simplify your program greatly.

Comment: @zk9 This is actually a very simple assignment. Basically just reading and outputting to file.

Comment: There are 5 methods, these 3 I am lost in. I'm trying to read and write a file and also append it.

Comment: @zk9 Where are you lost, from the method name itself everything pretty much seemed self-explanatory. In recordHighScore() just write the data back into text file. If you can't use BufferedReader, just use a File Scanner.

Comment: For example, the text file has names and numbers(score) how do you read only the number? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @zk9 Just use a String.split() method. If not, just get index of the delimiter, and get the substring after the index. Many ways to do it. Yes, you have to separate the string and the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert data into text files. You can only append/rewrite. These are the steps:

- Read data and store into objects.
- Get the highest/lowest from the objects (you can also sort them with `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()`)
- Write the sorted objects back into the text file. (You will be overwriting the text file with new data)