# how to split arraylist<File> with "/"

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a shell. on the console when a user enter `cd "path"` the current directory will change in the given path. When a user enters `find "filename"` my program will search that file in that directory and return the path of that directory.

I write a method that prints all the files including subDirectories on that directory... but I don't understand how to find the specific file that a user enters and print the files path.

I think I have to split the path by `/` than store them into an `ArrayList` than equals them with user enter `"filename"`. I don't know how to split a path into an `ArrayList<File>`

The current state of my method:

```
public static void findFilesInDirectory()
    {
        ArrayList<File> anArray = new ArrayList<File>();
        String getDirectoryName = presentWorkingDirectory;

        findFilesProcess(getDirectoryName, anArray);


        for(File str: anArray)
        {

            System.out.println("Hamza Found File: " + str);

        }
    }
public static void findFilesProcess(String directoryName, ArrayList<File> files) 
{

        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList)
        {
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                files.add(file);
            } 
            else if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                findFilesProcess(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Please clarify the question further with example. It is difficult to deduce what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java filing and highscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241413/java-filing-and-highscore)

Comment: i have make a shell . i want user to enter "find" space "file name" than my code search that file on this directory and give user the path if the file exist

Comment: Mind that file paths are - like many things - more complicated than they look. For instance double slashes are seen as single slashes. The path `foo///bar//baz/qux///foobar` is equivalent with `foo/bar/baz/qux/foobar`.

Comment: Thanks. But how do i can solve this. any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

To find files in a directory:

```
public static File[] findFilesInDirectory(String presentWorkingDirectory) {
    // your directory
    File f = new File(presentWorkingDirectory);
    File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles();
    return matchingFiles;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have just string directory structure not the actual directory, you can use the following code snippet to get only file names from directory structure or just a file name:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> dirPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        dirPaths.add("/dir1/dir2/myfile1.txt");
        dirPaths.add("/dir1/myfile1.txt");
        dirPaths.add("/dir1/dir2/myfile2.txt");
        dirPaths.add("myfile.txt");
        for (String string : dirPaths)
        {
            String[] split = string.split("/");
            System.out.println(split[split.length - 1]);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
myfile1.txt
myfile1.txt
myfile2.txt
myfile.txt
```

Hope it helps you. Have a nice day. :-)

Comment: Thanks but this is not helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Ok @muhammad lets do like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // User input file name
        final String searchFileName = "";
        File f = null;
        File[] paths;
        try
        {
            // Your current working dir
            f = new File("c:/test");

            // create new filename filter
            FilenameFilter fileNameFilter = new FilenameFilter()
            {

                public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
                {
                    if (searchFileName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
            // returns pathnames for files and directory filtered by user search file name, now you just have to show path as per your requirement.
            paths = f.listFiles(fileNameFilter);

            // for each pathname in pathname array
            for (File path : paths)
            {
                // prints file and directory paths
                System.out.println("paths:" + path + " :: file name" + path.getName());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // if any error occurs
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hope at least this code snippet helps you. Have a nice day. :-)

Comment: Thanks alot. "c:/Users/Hamza/Downloads" this is the directory that user enter And find"filename" . Now i have to search that file name in all the subDirectories. can u help me with that...